# applying Singleton to Spotipy throws error

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, design-patterns, singleton

Spotipy's object needs to be passed a credential kw arg
my code:

```
import spotipy
class Spoti2(spotipy.Spotify):
    spoty_obj = None
    
    @classmethod
    def __new__(cls, client_credentials_manager):
        if cls.spoty_obj is None:
            cls.spoty_obj = super().__new__(cls)
            print('se creo instancia')
        return cls.spoty_obj
```

but i get the error:

```
Spoti2.__new__() got multiple values for argument 'client_credentials_manager'
```

however, when I remove `@classmethod`, it works, and I don't know why

Comment: **why** are you decorating `__new__` with `@classmethod`? That is not what the data model expects.

Comment: What's the point of this class? Why use a singleton? Why not just a regular function?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i will use the Spotify object from different scripts and i want to reuse the object instead of creating a new one

Comment: That didn't answer my question, **why use a singleton class** when you can just have a function, `def create_spotify_object()->` that returns an instance and caches that instance? You could just use the `@functools.cache` decorator and you wouldn't even have to write the caching logic.

Comment: because I wanted to practice doing design patterns xd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not supposed to add `@classmethod` to `__new__()`

From: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__

> special-cased so you need not declare it as [a static/class method]